# Создание база данных в Node JS без каких-либо модулей

Tags: node.js

Доброго времени суток, товарищи!
Нужна помощь! Я начал работать над одним проектом в Node JS, и по принципу MVC я хочу сперва создать база данных с нуля, без каких-либо сторонних модулей, программ, фреймворков и т.д. Помогите, как и с чего начать. Но знаю одной, что для этого нужен JSON.
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Для чего база данных-то?

Answer (score 0):

Самое банальное это

```
var mydbdb = {}
//потом писать изменения на диск
fs.writeFileSync("./mydbdb.json", JSON.stringify(weights_JSON), 'utf8');
//и при запуске программы считывать так
var mydbdb = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./mydbdb.json"));
```

Единственное это не всегда корректно работает с некоторыми объектами, например RegEx будет записан как *[Object]*

Если что есть уже готовая обёртка такого типа в виде **NeDB**.